# I shut my lid on system updates

Tags: updates

It wasn't an upgrade, i just shut the lid like an idiot. Its an acer and the computer is still running but should I wait til the morning or just shut it off and boot it back up again?

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade Ubuntu and is the upgrade process taking time?

Comment: No i had like 425 updates from update manager. Im on oneirc ocelot and it was maybe a quarter done, not even halfway on the updates and i dont know wha it was working on but stupid me i shut my laptop lid and then realised, omg it was still on updates. Not upgrade to 12 pangolin. The light is still on and the computer is running but i would have to force it to shut off. Would it make me redo my system if i did that? Like it does IF you are upGRADING? Should i just shut it off or wait till morning tk try and shut it off?

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine, as long as the downloads had not finished when the lid was shut. Ubuntu downloads all of the updated packages before installing the packages, since it sometimes has to use dependencies that are included in the update.